# ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms Custom 404 Page Best Practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, urlrewriter.net

Well, for about one week, I have been searching the web, trying my own solutions and testing the results. But unfortunately I did not end up to the satisfying result that is needed.

**Problem Details:**

- Using IIS 7.5

The problem is that; either using `Response.Redirect();` method or declaring `customErrors` and `httpErrors` sections in the "Web.Config" file the very first status code sent to the browser is 302 then the 404.

Using `Server.Transfer();` method or even modifying the `QueryString[]` collection within the `Page_Load();` using *System.Reflection* this sends 404 status code directly to the browser but the "Page Name" (URL) is not my custom 404 page's name, but the requested non-existing page URL, which is a big problem (This can be checked using Google Chrome developer tools > Network pane), I have tried a workaround for this by changing the URL in the address bar of the browser using JavaScript `window.history.pushState();` but this did not make a difference.

**My Question is:**

What is the best practice for a custom 404 page in ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5; Sending 404 HTTP status code directly as the very first response, preserving the 404 page URL in the address bar (without redirects and no JavaScript)?

***Note:*** If any other information I am missing for an optimal 404 page to be detected and recognized by Google, please list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7.5, after using this, 404 page was successfully recognized by testers.

I have figured out that there is no need to keep the 404 page address constant, it could be the URL of the non-existing page.

Thanks for Help.